# This() vs Target() aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

Can anyone explain the difference between `this()` and `target()` pointcuts in aspectj. I tried finding this elsewhere but there doesnt seem to be a clear cut answer. Thank You

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At a matching join point, `this()` is the object you are in, `target()` is the object you are invoking/referencing. The confusion may arise because in the case of an `execution()` pointcut matching on a joint point they are the same thing - the object containing the execution join point which matched is the same as the object running the method you are matching on. But in the case of a `call()` join point they are different. The object making the call is different from the object on which the method is being called.

```
class A {
  public void m() {
    B b = new B();
    b.n();
  }
}
class B {
  public void n() {
  }
}
```

For that setup, the pointcut `execution(* m(..))` will match on join point `A.m()` and have a `this()` of type A and `target()` of type A (and they will be the same instance of A).  However the pointcut `call(* n(..))` will match at the call site in method `A.m()` where it calls `n()` and at that point `this()` will be the instance of A making the call whilst `target()` will be the instance of B that the method is being invoked upon.

Comment: If you want more info, visit this link https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#:~:text=its%20a%20supertypes.-,call%20vs.%20execution,-When%20methods%20and, which more or less says what @Andy Clement, and mentions a use case.

Comment: In addition, Spring AOP corroborates the answer: ```In addition, AspectJ itself has type-based semantics and at an execution join point both this and target refer to the same object - the object executing the method``` (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)